# Did not understand the outputs

Tags: python, loops, if-statement

**My code:**

```
num = 5
if num > 2:  
    print(num)
    num -= 1
print(num)
```

**Expected output:**

```
5,4,3,2
```

**Actual output:**

```
5,4
```

**Question:** Why do I receive the actual output and not the expected output?

Comment: It only contains 2 print statements.. why would you expect it to print out 4 things?

Comment: This is not the `if-loop` you are looking for ....

Comment: There is no loop Fabio - `for` and `while` are used for creating loops

Comment: [Have a read of this](https://www.learnpython.org/en/Loops)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to have confused `if` and `while`. `if` only runs at most once. `while` will run any number of times until the condition is false.

```
while num > 2:
    ...
```

Comment: You are right tried with while and had my first expected outputs.Thanks

Comment: @FábiodeAbreu, If this answer solved your question you should mark it as *"chosen"* by clicking the tick under the votes counter (left of the answer). It will tell other users who reach this question that the solution works, it will give you rep. points, it'll give the person who answered rep. points... Everybody happy! **:-)** See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234

Answer (score 1):

Your `if` should be a `while` if you want the result to be as you expected:

```
while num > 2:
    print(num)
    num -= 1
print(num)

> 5
> 4
> 3
> 2
```